# Como imprimir vector de 5 caracteres, y que te permita devolver el valor dentro del vector en C

Tags: array, c

Estoy corriendo este codigo en C (con Atom) y me tira error.
No puedo hacer que me imprima los caracteres que le ingreso, y me tira error. No se donde esta el error. Más aún, me dice que la cadena no es un char, cuando esta puesto que si.
Osea, al final de la funcion leerChar, en return, me dice que está mal eso. Pero porque?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define L 100
#define X 5

char leerChar(char mensaje[])
{
  char cadena[L];
  int e=0,continuar;
do {
  printf("%s",mensaje);
  fgets(cadena, L, stdin);
  setbuf(stdin, NULL);
  cadena[L-1] = '\0';
  while(cadena[e] != '\r' && cadena[e] != '\n' && cadena[e] != '\0')
  {
    e++;
  }
  cadena[e] = '\0';
  continuar=1;
  for (e = 0; e < strlen(cadena); e++)
  {
    if(isdigit(cadena[e]))
    {
      printf("Caracter no valido\n");
      continuar=0;
      break;
    }
  }
}while(continuar==0);
return (cadena);
}

int main()
{
  char cadena[L];
  char carac[X];
  int i;
  printf("- Ingrese 5 caracteres -\n");
  for(i = 0; i < X; i++)
  {
    snprintf(cadena, L, "Caracter numero %d: ", i+1);
    carac[i]=leerChar(cadena);
  }
  printf("\nLas caracteres guardados fueron:\n");
  for(i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    printf("Caracter: %c\n", i+1, carac[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

*Alguien sabe que hacer en este caso?*
*Donde está el error?*

Answer (score 1):

> > Alguien sabe que hacer en este caso? Donde está el error?

El error radica en esta línea:

```c
return (cadena);
```

La función `leerChar` retorna únicamente un **caracter**. Por lo tanto, el identificador `cadena` no es de tipo `char`, sino, de tipo `char[]` (es un tipo que se usa para definir **arrays** en C).

**Solución:** Como la función `leerChar` pide al usuario únicamente un caracter, entonces asumiremos que ese **caracter** está en la primera posición del *array* `cadena`.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
return cadena[0];
```

De este modo no saldrá ningún error de compilación, ya que la expresión `cadena[0]` es de tipo `char` y hará que la función retorna **únicamente un caracter**.

**Observación:**

**1.-** La función `fgets` en este caso pide una secuencia de caracteres y no únicamente un caracter. Así que lo ideal sería usar la función `scanf` junto con el especificador de formato `%c`. De este modo, hacemos el código más sencillo.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
char leerChar(char mensaje[])
{
    char caracter;
    int continuar;
    do 
    {
        continuar = 1;
        printf("%s",mensaje);
        scanf("%c", &caracter);
        /* Limpiamos el búfer del teclado. */
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        if(isdigit(caracter))
        {
            printf("Caracter no valido\n");
            continuar=0;
        }
    }while(continuar==0);
    return caracter;
}
```

**2.-** Esta sentencia no imprimirá lo esperado:

```c
printf("Caracter: %c\n", i+1, carac[i]);
```

Falta un especificador `%d` para poder imprimir el dato que genera la expresión `i+1`:

```c
printf("Caracter: %d %c\n", i+1, carac[i]);
```